# How to make a Squire shape using CSS depending on element width without any JavaScript

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a div/button element, can I make it a Squire shape using their parent width how to achieve this.

```css
    button {
       width: 150px;
       background: red;
       color: white;
       outline: 0;
    }
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

Here the screenshot for result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to set width & height for parent and set button width & height to 100%

```css
.parent {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

or set `height: 150px` for button so it will be squire!

Comment: this isn't appropriate answer, I can set only one width or height, then automatic make it without javascript